# Issue with sql query in GO

Tags: mysql, go

I have a really simple mysql table, with 3 columns, A, B and C.

A and B are keys.

I have a GO app and I'm trying to retrieve data from db. With other queries works like a charm, but with this one it doesn't:

```
aParam := "aValue"
bParam := "3,4,6,9"
stmt, err := o.database.Prepare("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE `A`= ? AND `B` IN ( ? )")
defer stmt.Close()
rows, err := stmt.Query(aParam, bParam)
for rows.Next() {
...
}
```

If I replace the second ? for the values, it works perfect:

```
stmt, err := o.database.Prepare("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE `A`= ? AND `B` IN ( 3,4,6,9 )")
```

I also tried with this (it doesn't work):

```
stmt, err := o.database.Prepare("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE `A`= ? AND `B` IN ( " + bParam +" )")
```

Any idea?

Comment: What DB driver are you using? Popular Go DB drivers often don't support `IN` queries very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the single `?` is not expanded into the `SELECT` statement (like a string replace), but as a single string value `3,4,5,6`

You need to expand each value of the `IN` clause as such:

```
params := []interface{} { "aValue", 3, 4, 6, 9 }
stmt, err := o.database.Prepare("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE `A`= ? AND `B` IN ( ?, ?, ?, ? )")
defer stmt.Close()
rows, err := stmt.Query(params...)
```

To make your life easier, you can use a package like [sqlx](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#inQueries), which has better support for parameterized `IN` queries

Comment: another option would be to populate temporary table to keep 'IN' list and then use this table in the query (either join or IN subquery).  This way you are not bounded too much handling varying size of IN list.

Comment: ok, just another question, here:  

    params := []interface{} { "aValue", 3, 4, 6, 9 }  

I need to add dynamically those values, I not even know how many they are going to be

Comment: you would need to generate a string of ?'s for the IN clause matching the number of IDs you need